# Dask - average of timestamp difference between lines during groupby

Tags: datetime, aggregate, dask, mean

I try to perform with Dask an average of the timestamp difference between group lines (two by two), during an aggregation.

An example of dataframe would be :

```
   Timestamp            IP         Packets
0  2021-07-12 09:54:36  10.42.0.1  25
1  2021-07-12 09:54:36  10.41.0.1  5
2  2021-07-12 09:54:39  10.42.0.1  3
3  2021-07-12 09:54:46  10.41.0.1  30
4  2021-07-12 09:54:52  10.42.0.1  2
```

According to this [documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html?highlight=Aggregation#custom-aggregation), I tried something like this:

```py
diffMean = dd.Aggregation('diffMean', lambda x: x.diff(), lambda x0: x0.mean().compute())
    
myDf = (df.groupby(['IP']).agg({ 'Packets': ['sum', 'mean'], 'Timestamp': ['min', 'max', diffMean]}).compute())
```

The expected result is :

```
           Packets    Timestamp
           sum  mean  min                  max                  diffMean
IP         
10.41.0.1  35   17.5  2021-07-12 09:54:36  2021-07-12 09:54:46  00:00:10 # 10 = 10 / 1
10.42.0.1  30   10    2021-07-12 09:54:36  2021-07-12 09:54:52  00:00:08 # 8 = (3 + 13) / 2
```

But Dask does not like my aggregation... It gives me the following error:

```py
...
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/flip/bin/resSys", line 185, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/flip/bin/resSys", line 153, in main
    nb256 = processTemplates(ipfix, 256, directory)
  File "/home/flip/bin/resSys", line 120, in 
    ...
  File "/home/flip/bin/resSys", line 87, in process256
    myDf = (df.groupby(['IP']).agg({ 'Packets': ['sum', 'mean'], 'Timestamp': ['min', 'max', diffMean]}).compute())
  File "/home/flip/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/groupby.py", line 1847, in agg
    return self.aggregate(arg, split_every=split_every, split_out=split_out)
  File "/home/flip/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/groupby.py", line 1843, in aggregate
    return super().aggregate(arg, split_every=split_every, split_out=split_out)
  File "/home/flip/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/groupby.py", line 1623, in aggregate
    sort=self.sort,
  File "/home/flip/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 5563, in apply_concat_apply
    meta_chunk = _emulate(chunk, *args, udf=True, **chunk_kwargs)
  File "/home/flip/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 5612, in _emulate
    return func(*_extract_meta(args, True), **_extract_meta(kwargs, True))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/flip/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/utils.py", line 197, in raise_on_meta_error
    raise ValueError(msg) from e
ValueError: Metadata inference failed in `_groupby_apply_funcs`.

You have supplied a custom function and Dask is unable to
determine the type of output that that function returns.

To resolve this please provide a meta= keyword.
The docstring of the Dask function you ran should have more information.

Original error is below:
------------------------
NotImplementedError('Can only union MultiIndex with MultiIndex or Index of tuples, try mi.to_flat_index().union(other) instead.')

Traceback:
---------
  ...
```

The problem is that `dd.Aggregation` does not accept a "meta" parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some pointers that could potentially help you.

#### 1. Remove the `compute` from the aggregation

I think the `compute` should be removed from the aggregation. As far as I can tell, aggregation operates on Pandas dataframes.

```py
diffMean = dd.Aggregation('diffMean', lambda x: x.diff(), lambda x0: x0.mean())
```

#### 2. Consider converting timestamps to `int`

I have tried to reproduce the problem in the following way

```py
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd

# Create some artificial data
df = dask.datasets.timeseries().reset_index()

diffMean = dd.Aggregation('diffMean', lambda x: x.diff(), lambda x0: x0.mean())    
(df.groupby(['name'])
  .agg({ 'x': ['sum', 'mean'], 'timestamp': ['min', 'max', diffMean]})
  .compute())
```

this fails, possibly because it cannot deal with a timestamp column somewhere along the road. Converting to `int` worked for me:

```py
(df.astype({'timestamp': int})
  .groupby(['name'])
  .agg({ 'x': ['sum', 'mean'], 'timestamp': ['min', 'max', diffMean]})
  .compute())
```

#### 3. MultiIndex

The original error that your code raises is

```py
NotImplementedError('Can only union MultiIndex with MultiIndex or Index of tuples, try mi.to_flat_index().union(other) instead.')
```

In your example, you don't seem to have a MultiIndex in the dataframe, so I am not sure what the problem could be there. Perhaps this is a matter of dask version? I reproduced / fixed this on `2021.06.2`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! Indeed, by implementing your solutions on my test dataframe, I have no more exceptions thrown.  Nevertheless on my real dataset which is much bigger in number of columns and rows, the error is still present. Do you think this could be due to the size of the dataset?
Moreover on this test set, the result that is returned to me does not correspond to the expected one, here is what is returned to me: 
 Would you have an idea for this problem too ?

Comment: Packets           Timest  
              sum  mean           min           max      diffMean  
0             0.0   NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN  
1             0.0   NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN  
2             0.0   NaN           NaN           NaN  3.000000e+09  
3             0.0   NaN           NaN           NaN  1.000000e+10  
4             0.0   NaN           NaN           NaN  1.300000e+10  
10.41.0.1    35.0  17.5  1.626084e+18  1.626084e+18           NaN  
10.42.0.1    30.0  10.0  1.626084e+18  1.626084e+18           NaN

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to format properly my result... The problem is that I don't have only the two lines with my two IP addresses as index, but the two IP addresses plus the previous index (from 0 to 4). And the diffMean values for my IP addresses are at NaN.